# How to intercept all exceptions in a Spring MVC web application and how to store a lot of informations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, web-applications

In a web application (Spring 3.1.2 MVC), I need to intercept all exceptions to store informations in a database. It's like a logger (it's already configure in the log4j.xml file) but the idea it's to keep informations in a specific database table.
So how can I handle all exception by aspect? by filter? by interceptor? Not by @ControllerAdvice (since Spring 3.2) because the project is build with Spring 3.1.

And in a second time, when I catch the exception, how can I handle that, how can I retrieve a lot of informations: request url, referer url, class, line, objects states (class + values)?

Some frameworks exists for that (intercept and store exceptions)?

Comment: log4j already has a database logger or at least logback has one. It logs everything you log to a database instead of file. To handle exceptions you could use an after throwing advice and do the logging. For all the additional information, create a filter that sets the values in the MDC. (Logback provides one out-of-the-box).

Comment: Have you tried looking at using `@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch) which provides an appender for the database out-out-of-the-box. The [`DBAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender) basically writes all logging information to the database, the stack trace, the message and the MDC (when set).

To add additional attributes to your logging you can register the [`MDCInsertingServletFilter`] which will add things like URL, remote ip, username (if available) to the MDC (and as such will be logged).

For the other information you can specify [a pattern](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout) to include the desired information.

To log all exceptions you can create an after throwing advice and have that applied to your classes. One tricky thing is to make sure your exceptions are being logged only once instead of over and over.